# How do I remove a project reference from a website project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

So, if I have website project Foo which has a reference to class library project Bar, how do I remove that reference?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reference is stored in the Visual Studio solution file.

Right-click on the web site's project item in Solution Explorer and choose "Property Pages". The first item on the dialog that comes up is "References".  You can add/remove references from here.

**Edit:**

I should mention that this is in Visual Studio 2010. I don't have any other versions installed at the moment, so I can't verify that this works for them as well.

Comment: For other versions of Visual Studio and more details, simply go to [How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 (at least in my copy) the "Property Pages" window only allows me to view the references. To add a reference I have to right-click the project and then Add > Reference..., but since I've already removed some projects from the solution they don't appear at this window, so I'm unable to build the website because it references those unavailable projects and I'm unable to remove these references from the website (at least through the GUI, AFAIK). LOL

Comment: @Nicolas, I took a quick look at that page, and the section about removing references seemed to only apply to non-website projects. Not sure if I missed something?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did it for Visual Studio 2017.

1. Close the solution in Visual Studio
2. Open the solution file (`.sln`) in a text editor
3. Locate the website project: `Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "YOUR-WEBSITE-NAME"`
4. Locate the `ProjectReferences` property under the project
5. The reference you want to delete might look like `{03D389EB-38E0-4D71-86EF-E2ABCFB4AE21}|REFERENCE-TO-REMOVE.dll;`
6. Delete it from within the string, including the semicolon

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in all versions of Visual Studio 2005-2010 that make you think you are deleting a project reference, but when you try to add the reference back, it says it already exists.
Solution: delete the solution file (SLN) and re-add all the projects back. This is the ONLY solution that works unless you can edit the solution file directly (which almost never works).

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2013, there is no direct option, you have to delete all dlls in bin/debug , and clean, re build solution, you are done.

Comment: This didn't work for me. In my version of VS2013, website references are maintained in the solution file with no ability to remove the reference from within the IDE.

You will need to open the solution file in Notepad and remove the references, save and then reopen the solution

Comment: For VS2015, This.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, Right-click on the project. In this view, go to References, and remove the offending reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in 2008 but removing the reference didn't work, it just kept coming back. I ended up editing the solution file in notepad and removing the reference manually.